# Controlling ExceptionValidationRule at Button binded to a ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a button into a WPF window binded to a ICommand

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonSearchTime}">
    <Button.Command>
        <Binding Path="FiltrarPlanillasCommand">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

an this is the method for execute

```
public void FiltrarPlanillasExecute(object p)
{
    FiltrosDocumento filtro = new FiltrosDocumento();
    filtro.ListaBodegasAcopio = ListaBodegasSeleccionadas;
    filtro.FechaInicial = FechaInicial;
    filtro.FechaFinal = FechaFinal;
    filtro.IntIdmodulo = IntIdModulo;
    try
    {
        filtro.PlanillaAcopioLiquidada = PlanillaAcopioLiquidada;

        ListaPlanillas = null;
        ListaPlanillas = new ObservableCollection<Merlin_MovimientoDocumentosFacturacion_Enc>(
                    ListaDocumentos.PlanillasAcopio(filtro, db)
                );
        ((DelegateCommand)_ICommandParadigmaNPrint).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //    Here this exception wasn't catched 
        throw;
    }
}
```

Why if `<ExceptionValidationRule/>` was setted, it doesn't catch the Exception? 
Whats wrong on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExceptionValidationRule is used to catch the exception occurs at the properties' set or get method, but not the execute method of the command property you binding to.

Comment: Do you know another aproach to acomplish this task, I have many objects binded to a Commands and in each command perform some validations and need to show it to the user avoinding to use MessageBox. Tks for your help